# How to catch an event in angularjs to apply the scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a some kind of error reporter in my app. It's logic is pretty simple:

```
$scope.showError = function (text) {
        var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector('reporter div:first-child'));
        elem.removeClass("notice");
        $scope.reporterMessage = text;
        $scope.displayReporter = true;
        if (!event) {
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    };
```

This `showError` function might be called inside `ng-click` (and also inside others angular's events) handlers, so then `$scope.apply()` is not required. But this function also might be called from elsewhere manually, that's why I should use `$scope.apply()` to show the reporter.

How I can find out when this function was called inside angular's event and when it wasn't. The code above works great in Chrome, but doesn't work in Firefox, because there is no `event` keyword in Firefox.

I also know that I just can use some kind of flag like this `showError(text, applyScope)`, but this is not good idea, I think, because I will have to change function calls everywhere. There are realy big amount of them.

Can I solve the problem only inside of `showError` function, without changing it's calls?

Comment: Can you show me a typical usage of this function outside angular?

Comment: @YeLiu, For example, I can call it from developer console. `angular.element(document.querySelector('reporter div')).scope().showError("someText");`